# Initialising AWS in a Java Applet on a Spring server

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, applet

I am trying to use Amazon's SDK to upload files to Amazon S3 from a Java applet. The applet sits on a web server running Spring.

The problem is that before I try to upload my file I need to initialise the Amazon S3 client. This is usually pretty simple:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

But when I do that, the second line triggers this error message (regardless of whether the credentials are correct or not):

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1008813135 in class file <!DOCTYPE html>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1131) ~[upload.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:1065) ~[upload.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:1062) ~[upload.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:569) ~[upload.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685) ~[upload.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<clinit>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:56) ~[upload.jar:na]
```

What's happening here is the AWS library is trying to initialise its logging system, so it starts searching for the LogFactory that's going to handle any internal logging messages. The problem is it starts to search outside of the applet, by making a GET request for

```
http://localhost/...myUrl.../commons-logging.properties
```

(I found this out from the docs here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/package-summary.html)

Now, a quick side note: My `security-app-context.xml` file for Spring contains the following entry point bean to make sure non-authenticated users only see the log-in page:

```
<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/loginPage" />
</beans:bean>
```

It's at this stage that my Spring set-up is catching the GET request and redirecting it to the server log-in page. This redirect ends up sending a valid HTML page as the result of this GET request. The HTML page's first line is '', which the Logging Framework parses and tries to use that to initialise a Java class. Obviously a class called .class doesn't exist, so I get the ClassFormatError.

Is there a way to get the AWS library to play nicely with this set up? Ideally without disabling Spring's redirection policy.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... but do you really think that it is a good idea to distribute your aws credentials in an applet ? (running on client machine !)

Comment: That's a fair point, and under normal circumstances I'd agree. However, in this case the AWS credentials are for an account with strictly limited access rights and access to the applet itself is protected by an the same log-in system I'm trying to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around that particular error by telling the logging framework exactly where to find a LogFactory implementation by putting this line in somewhere before the `new AmazonS3Client()` call:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl");
```

However, you may find the same problem appears with a different file, two of them in fact, this time a bit deeper inside Amazon's library. Again, they are searched for using GET requests (as seen in the Java console).

```
http://localhost/...myUrl.../com/amazonaws/services/s3/request.handlers
http://localhost/...myUrl.../com/amazonaws/services/s3/request.handler2s
```

So, you need a file called `request.handlers` and another called `request.handler2s`, both inside a folder structure of `com/amazonaws/services/s3`, with the `com` folder in one of your Classpath folders (Probably the root of your applet's JAR file). The files should be empty.

With the LogFactory property set to prevent searching for commons-logging.properties, and the Amazon request handler files in place the initialisation should complete successfully.

(This answer feels a bit unwieldy and I'm not completely happy with it, so alternatives are very welcome).